# How to handle Error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'", when converting list to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping

Trying to create a dataframe from a list but get error 
"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

person = []
position = []
skaterstats = []
person = []
player_id = {}
 for game_id in range(2018020001, 2018020002, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/feed/live'.format(game_id)
    r = requests.get(url)
    game_data = r.json()

for homeaway in ['home','away']:
    player_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('skaters')
    player_id[homeaway] = player_dict

for homeaway in player_id:
    for playerID in player_id[homeaway]:
        play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('person')
        play_dict_position = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('position')
        play_dict_skaterstats = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('stats').get('skaterStats')
        person.append(play_dict_person)
        position.append(play_dict_position)
        skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)

df_person = pd.DataFrame(person).head()
df_position = pd.DataFrame(position).head()
df_skaterstats = pd.DataFrame(skaterstats).head()

----> 3 df_skaterstats = pd.DataFrame(skaterstats).head() 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

The error occurs occurs only on this DataFrame, I have checked that the path should be correct and all. Link to the API below if it would to any guidance.

This is the API: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020002/feed/live

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some players have no statistics, so `play_dict_skaterstats` for them is `None`. You might need to replace

```
skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)
```

with

```
if play_dict_skaterstats: 
    skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)
```

to skip these cases

Or you might need to set default values for this case, e.g.

```
if not play_dict_skaterstats:
    play_dict_skaterstats = {}
    play_dict_skaterstats['timeOnIce'] = None
    play_dict_skaterstats['assists'] = None
    ...
skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you again Mister. Andersson, you truly are a wizard!